# Why doesn't Flash teleport me through/over walls?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have done this so many times that I don't even use Flash anymore. I'll be running to a wall or standing near one and I'll just flash into the wall and not go over it.

What makes this happen? Is there a target distance on Flash like Corki's Valkyrie or does Flash just not work sometimes? In the description it says it moves target champion towards the direction of the mouse, but why can't I get over the wall half the time?

Answer (score 2):

Flash has a limited range. It works over some walls and trees, but not all of them!

Just hold your cursor over the flash button and you can see its range around your hero.

Answer (score 0):

It follows your mouse... always thought it was just like Nidalee's jump but no, it's cursor based.

Answer (score 0):

As these gentlemen said. it does have a range. as well at it follows to where your cursor is, like most skillshots. you will get a feel for it over time, and it will happen less and less as your play. :D